# Disable dictionary results in Spotlight?

Tags: spotlight

How can I remove dictionary results from Spotlight results? I've typed "chrome" into Spotlight and looked up *chrome* in the Dictionary one too many times, and now opening Chrome takes an extra keystroke.

I've seen comments about `defaults write com.apple.spotlight DictionaryLookupEnabled NO`, but this doesn't seem to work with Mac OS 10.8, even after a `sudo killall -u _spotlight`.

Comment: Just start Chrome via Spotlight a few times and it should move to the top again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TinkerTool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html) also allows you to change this preference via a GUI (rather than a Terminal command). It's under Applications > Spotlight:

[image]

Note that you will have to log out and back in for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

- Open /Applications/Utilities/Terminal
- Enter `defaults write com.apple.spotlight DictionaryLookupEnabled NO`
- Log out and Log back in

Please note that on some versions of OS X, Spotlight is part of the SystemUIServer process, and therefore cannot be killed using `killall Spotlight`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications in the edit comment, I've included them in the answer now to avoid further re-edits of this part.